# how to differentiate a new log in (new Session) and a session time out

Tags: jsf, session-timeout

Could someone let me know how to differentiate a new log in (new Session) and a session time out .
Only on login : user must be authenticated and redirected to a servlet to load user details (on other screnarios user must not be redirected to the servlet) 
and on timeout user must be redirected to the timeout page.
To identify a new session (user not logged in):
-- Session attributes cannot be used since the session becomes null on timeout.
-- Setting cookies for session management didnt work. 
The cookies are getting removed for the current session

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("activeSession", null);
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setValue("");
httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
getCookieValue(httpServletRequest , "activeSession"); returns null
public static String getCookieValue(HttpServletRequest request, String name) {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie != null && name.equals(cookie.getName())) {
                return cookie.getValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

After logout or Timeout (session is invalidated) when user logs in and a new session is created.
The cookies that were removed in the previous sessions reappears with the  preset values.

```
 getCookieValue(httpServletRequest , "activeSession") returns a value;
```

If I use the below approach it works for the 1 st login attempt. 
After the first login session has timedout ,the filter redirects to timeout page. 
The actual problem arises when user accesses the application in the same window after timeout.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,FilterChain   filterChain) throws IOException,
{   if ((request instanceof HttpServletRequest)
            && (response instanceof HttpServletResponse)) {
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

//Check for a new login 
if (httpServletRequest.getSession(false) == null  && httpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId()==null)
{
// Create a new session
httpServletRequest.getSession();
//Redirect to servlet on 1 st login to fetch details from DB
httpRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/loginServlet").forward(request,response);
}else{

//validate active or timedout sessions. 
boolean isSessionValid = (httpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId() != null) && !httpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid();

if(isSessionValid)
{
httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(getTimeoutPage());
}
}
}
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Therefore the details are not fetched from DB and the page is not loaded correctly.

Browser:IE 8
Server : Weblogic server

Answer (score 2):

Your cookie approach is unnecessary and technically invalid. A max age of `0` makes it to expire immediately when the response is processed. But anyway, you don't need an additional cookie. The `HttpSession` is by itself already backed by a cookie and the Servlet API already offers methods to check the one and other. Just store the logged-in user as an attribute of the `HttpSession` (which can in turn be a session scoped JSF managed bean).

The following example should do, assuming that you've stored the logged-in user as a property of a session scoped JSF managed bean with the managed bean name "auth".

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain   chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    Authenticator auth = (Authenticator) req.getSession().getAttribute("auth");

    if (req.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !req.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
        res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/timeout.xhtml");
    } else if (auth == null || !auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```